# Formatting Decimal Types for easy to consume Console display?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I'm outputing decimal types to the console. I don't want to display the entire decimal number,  just enough so the user has the data they need.

The problem is the relevant display precision will vary drastically through the program.  I don't know just how far past decimal to display.

This...

916.950000000000045474735088646411895751953125

...contains necessary precision for the program, but entirely unnecessary for the user to see.

Instead I want user to see this:

916.95

But I could just as easily have this:

916.95000350000000045474735088646411895751953125

And user needs to see this:

916.9500035

If I convert the Decimal type to float before displaying it, I get the necessary display precision.  But this adds yet more processor time.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something I don't see how those answers will tell me how to get the precision that a float number would be vs the same decimal number, or any way to get the display precision other then what is specified manually.

Comment: Should've pinged me if you think that doesn't answer your question, Emily. I'm going to open this again, you might want to edit your question to highlight why those answers won't work for you or someone else might come along and close it again to the same target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print your number with the precision you want using :

```
print '%.2f' %  value
```

Also, if you want to round your number before printing it :

```
round (value, 2)
```

In those two examples, you can set '2' as another number, specifying the precision you want.

If you don't know the precision you want, you could use this, setting a max of digits to be print in the decimal part :

```
def print_dec(number, max) :
    integer = int(number)
    decimal = str(number-integer)[2:]
    #Truncate the decimal part to max
    decimal = decimal[:max]
    #Remove '0'
    for c in reversed(decimal) :
        if c == '0' :
            decimal = decimal[:-1]
        else :
            break;
    # Reconstruct the number for printing
    print ("{}.{}".format(integer, decimal))
```

This way, you will have :

```
a = 916.95030000
print_dec (a, 1)
print_dec (a, 2)
print_dec (a, 5)
print_dec (a, 6)

>> 916.9
>> 916.95
>> 916.9503
>> 916.9503
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is I don't know the precision I need to display.  If there was a way to simply cut off all the extra precision a Decimal type adds to a number, that should do it.  Can that be done?

Comment: Actually, you could use your number as a string and set a maximal length for your decimal part. You could remove everything after the 10th value and then remove pending '0' from the end. Should it be right ?

Comment: I edit my post with a solution where you don't know the precision you want.

Comment: You should probably first `round` the number to the precision defined by `max`.